# How to check if WMIC outputs an empty string or the requested original product key of Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmic

I try to use a `wmic` command to check for the Windows product key. I put a check to see if it is returning the Windows product key or an empty line. But the conditions `IF "%%Z" == ""` as well as `IF [%%Z] EQU []` result always in execution of `Echo Lose`, i.e. key is not an empty string.

The following example is a simpler version to show the first part.

```
@ECHO OFF

set cmd=wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey
for /f "tokens=1 skip=1" %%Z in ('%cmd% ^| findstr /r /v "^$"') do (set RESULT=%%Z)

IF "%%Z" == "" (Echo Key %RESULT%) Else (Echo Lose)
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string value assigned to a loop variable like `Z` cannot be referenced outside of the loop. The condition `IF "%%Z" == ""` compares always the fixed string `"%Z"` with the fixed string `""` which are of course never equal. The condition `IF [%%Z] EQU []` results first in the attempt to convert the fixed string `[%Z]` into a 32-bit signed integer value which fails already on first character `[` and for that reason there is done next a string comparison of `[%Z]` with `[]` which are never equal too.

Some facts to know before using the code below:

- The [SoftwareLicensingService class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/slwmiprov/softwarelicensingservice-vista) is available only on Windows Vista or newer Windows client versions and on Windows Server 2008 and newer Windows server versions. This class has no property `OA3xOriginalProductKey` on Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008.
  The [SoftwareLicensingService class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/sppwmi/softwarelicensingservice) of Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 does not have the property `OA3xOriginalProductKey` too.
- There is not written much about `OA3xOriginalProductKey` in the Microsoft documentations. There are the Microsoft documentation pages [Windows 10, version 1703 basic level Windows diagnostic events and fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/privacy/basic-level-windows-diagnostic-events-and-fields-1703) and [An OSD task sequence doesn't continue after Windows Setup or an in-place upgrade finishes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/mem/configmgr/os-deployment-task-sequence-not-continue) and [Deploy Windows 10 Enterprise licenses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/deploy-enterprise-licenses) with a little bit of information about `OA3xOriginalProductKey`. It looks like this property was introduced with [OEM Activation 3.0 system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/oem-activation-3) used for Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 client versions.

There could be used the following batch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "RESULT="
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe PATH SoftwareLicensingService GET OA3xOriginalProductKey /VALUE 2^>nul') do for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%J in ("%%I") do set "RESULT=%%K"
if not defined RESULT echo Lose& goto EndBatch
echo Key %RESULT%
rem Other commands making use of environment variable RESULT.
:EndBatch
endlocal
pause
```

The usage of **FINDSTR** to filter out the empty lines is of no real help in case of no value output by **WMIC** for property `OA3xOriginalProductKey` because of the Unicode output of **WMIC** encoded with UTF-16 Little Endian with byte order mark (BOM) is processed wrong by the `cmd.exe` instance started in background with option `/C` and the specified command line as additional arguments on redirecting the output to **FINDSTR** with conversion to a single byte per character encoding.

The environment variable `RESULT` is defined in this case with a single carriage return as string assigned to the environment variable.

The workaround for this quirks of `cmd.exe` on processing the Unicode output of **WMIC** is using the option `/VALUE` to get output the name of property `OA3xOriginalProductKey` and its value on one line with an equal sign between and two empty lines above and also below the data line.

All five captured lines are processed by **FOR** which usually ignores empty lines completely. But there is no empty line to process by **FOR** because of the bug of `cmd.exe` interpreting the UTF-16 encoded carriage return + line-feed (`0D 00 0A 00`)  as carriage return + carriage return + line-feed (`0D 0D 0A`) resulting in the four empty lines are interpreted as line with a single carriage return and the line with `OA3xOriginalProductKey=` at beginning as line having also an extra carriage return at the end.

For that reason each entire line with carriage return at end is assigned first to loop variable `I`.

One more **FOR** loop is used to process the **string** assigned to the loop variable `I` which results in removing the erroneous carriage return from the string value before processing it.

So for the four empty lines there is no string to process by the second **FOR** and so the four empty lines are indeed ignored.

The second **FOR** loop splits up the only line with text data into two substrings by using the equal sign as string delimiter. The first substring `OA3xOriginalProductKey` is assigned to loop variable `J` and the second substring after the equal sign is the key which is assigned to next but one loop `K` if there is a key at all as otherwise `K` is not defined and `%%K` on command **SET** executed next is replaced by an empty string.

The batch file defines with the first two lines the required execution environment completely and makes sure that the environment variable `RESULT` is by chance not already defined outside of the batch file with the third command line.

The **IF** condition after the long command line with the two **FOR** and the **SET** commands checks first if the environment variable `RESULT` is defined now with a real key (and not with just carriage return) to determine which **ECHO** command to execute next.

The long command line could be also:

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe PATH SoftwareLicensingService GET KeyManagementServiceMachine /VALUE 2^>nul') do for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%J in ("%%I") do set "RESULT=%%J"
```

In this case just the string after the `OA3xOriginalProductKey=` is assigned to specified loop variable `J` if there is a key output by **WMIC** at all. Otherwise there is nothing to assign to `J` by second **FOR** and for that reason the command **SET** is never executed at all resulting in `RESULT` still not existing in list of environment variables.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic path /?`
- `wmic path softwarelicensingservice /?`
- `wmic path softwarelicensingservice get /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background.